# How to load images in ImageView with delay?

Tags: android-imageview, android-gridview, android-gallery

I am trying to make gallery and display gridview of ImageViews, but with delay in loadtime of each thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Handler with postDelayed method and a Runnable then. You will find many samples.

Comment: Hi Devrim.. Yes your answer helped.. but later I used Picasso library to load images as easy solution. But I am marking your answer as accepted. thanks.. :)